# iOS MPMoviePlayerController can't judge if paused or automatically completed playing

Tags: ios, iphone

Have an issue, `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` sends me playbackState as `MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused` for both scenarios whether I pause or moviePlayer automatically finishes playing.

`MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped` is happening only if I do a manual stop i.e. `[moviePlayer stop]`

Any idea how to differ with automatically finished or paused scenario.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

> The following key may be found in the userInfo dictionary of a
>   MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification.
>
> Swift
>
> let MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey: String
>
> OBJECTIVE-C
>
> NSString *const
>   MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey;

Then

> The value of this key is an NSNumber containing an integer value that
>   represents one of the “MPMovieFinishReason” constants.

And MPMovieFinishReason is Enum there you have **PlaybackEnded** and **UserExited**

Declaration
SWIFT

```
enum MPMovieFinishReason : Int {
    case PlaybackEnded
    case PlaybackError
    case UserExited
}
```

OBJECTIVE-C

```
enum {
   MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded,
   MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError,
   MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited 
};
typedef NSInteger MPMovieFinishReason;
```

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieFinishReason) .

Comment: Thanks @Imran fro your suggestion. I was using this and the playbackState to determine if I have stopped the player or the player has stopped itself automatically. This is correct for all scenarios except one where some of the time MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification is getting triggered for [player pause]; After this The player will behave oddly. One more thing to note is It is always containing MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded value

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. I was actually doing [player stop] at place where it should not have. Hence after removing the unnecessary stop it worked like charm.